# How can I change screen's hardstatus color based on the logged in user?

Tags: bash, gnu-screen, colors, bashrc

I haven't edited/created a .screenrc file in a while, but this is what I'm currently using:

```
# Turn off the screen startup message
startup_message off

# Define format of bottom navigation/status/date/etc. line
hardstatus alwayslastline "%{yk}[ %H ] %-Lw%50>%{gk}(%{-}%n-%t%{gk})%{-}%+Lw%< %=%{yk}[ %c %d.%m.%Y ]"

# Increase scrollback buffer to 30000 lines
defscrollback 30000
```

I honestly don't remember what everything in my hardstatus line stands for, but I want to figure out how I could change the hostname color based on the user that is logged in. Is this even possible? Right now, the hostname is yellow when I'm logged in under any user; but I want it to be red if I'm root. Is this something that can be changed in my .bashrc file? I have this in my .bashrc to change new screen window names to the hostname of the server I'm connected to:

```
# Set screen window title
case "$TERM" in
screen)
  PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033k$HOSTNAME\033\\"'
  ;;
esac
```

Thanks for any help!

**EDIT**

I've tried adding this to my .bashrc file, but it just puts the ANSI code in-front of the hostname in my screen hardstatus:

```
case "$TERM" in
screen)
  if (( $UID == 0 )); then
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033k$FRED$HOSTNAME$RS\033\\"'
  else
    PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033k$HOSTNAME\033\\"'
  fi
  ;;
esac
```

**EDIT 2**

I've also added the actual ANSI color codes (ex: `\[\033[31m\]`) and the screen escape codes (ex: `%kr`) to the above statement in my `.bashrc`, but neither worked.

**EDIT 3**

If I use this as the prompt command line, the hostname appears in red in-front of my PS1:

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033[31m$HOSTNAME\033\\"'
```

If I use the following prompt, the window name changes to the hostname (YES!); but the color remains the default (NO!):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='echo -ne "\033[31m\033k$HOSTNAME\033\\"'
```

I've also tried replacing `\033[31m` (and just `[31m`) with the screen color escape (%kr), but that did not work either.

Comment: You want to color it based on the user you're logged in as of if a certain user is logged onto the system?

Comment: Yes. I want to make it so the server hostname turns red when I log into that server as root. For example, in my .bashrc file, I have a line that changes my PS1 to all red text when I log in as root. I want to emulate this behavior with the hostnames in screen.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this U&L Q&A.

- [How can you change the GNU screen status line based on hostname?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/16429/how-can-you-change-the-gnu-screen-status-line-based-on-hostname)

Specifically this answer, https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/16433/7453.

The general idea is that you maintain 2 different `screenrc` files with the colors and based on your `$USER` in your `bashrc` file you point the environment variable`SCREENRC` to the one for a given user.

Comment: I'll take a look. The only question I have regarding this is, will both `.screenrc` files work at the same time? For example, if I open screen as myself then `sudo -s` to root on another machine within that screen session, will my other screen windows stay yellow and the name (hostname) of the  window I just became root in turn red?

Comment: I don't know if that's possible, maybe it is, but it's still a bit too out of the ordinary, I mean, if you're inside the *same* screen session, it will be running using the same `.screenrc`. With two separate screen instances, it'd be plainly simple to do it, just two separate configs.

Comment: That is what I assumed, I'll keep searching and update the thread if I find a solution (or if someone else has one). Thanks for the help!